# What does it mean by "the theoretical resources to be drawn on"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

In [this file](https://www.macromedia-fachhochschule.de/uploads/tx_rtgfiles/Proposal_Anleitung_en_170904doc.pdf), I see that

> 4. Research methodology
>      You should provide an outline of:
>      • **the theoretical resources to be drawn on**
>      • the research approach (theoretical framework)
>      • the research methods appropriate for the proposed research
>      • a discussion of advantages as well as limits of particular approaches and methods

What does it mean by "the theoretical resources to be drawn on"?

Comment: It looks like a potential mistranslation to me. Is there an original German version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing an academic paper, it's common to include references to other works that you have used to support your own work. These could be referred to as resources, and I'd imagine that "theoretical resources" means works that discuss theories pertaining to what you are writing about/researching. It may not just refer to works in this context, but also to commonly accepted theories, i.e. which theories will be working assumptions in your paper.

"Drawn on" simply means that you are using them in you own work (using the definition of "draw" as "to pull or drag", i.e. to pull them into your work).

I do think the phrasing is a little abstract though, and I wouldn't see anything wrong with asking for clarification.